# Create a custom zoo element to show a badge if product is in Quick2Cart already

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, zoo-cck

I'm trying to create a custom Zoo element based on the Quick2Cart element, but I'm realizing  that there's a reason I'm not a programmer.

The quick2cart guys have helped a little bit by giving me this snippet:

```
function getitemid($product_id,$client)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT `item_id` FROM `#__kart_items`  where `product_id`=".(int)$product_id. " AND parent='$client'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
    return $result;
}
```

But I can't quite figure out how to write the element so it renders. All I really want is for the element to check to see if the item is for sale (meaning, it's set up in Quick2cart and is considered a product). If so, I want to display a little "Buy it!" badge that links to the zoo item.

The current Quick2Cart Zoo element has lots of extra stuff in it so I can't simply duplicate it or I'd end up with issues in the edit screen of the zoo item. I don't really want any interface at all for the element. All I really want is an "if it's a product, show this" kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TechJoomla guys helped me a bit with this. It could probably still be cleaned up, but it checks for the item and if the Quick2Cart item Id isn't empty and it's a zoo item (so we don't accidentally check for another type of item), it displays a little badge that links to the zoo item.

Building the element itself is based on this document:
[Create A Custom Element][1]

in the php file here's what I ended up with:

```
        <?php

class ElementQtc_available extends Element {

    public function edit() {
    }

    public function render($params = array()) {

    }

    public function hasValue($product_id,$client) 
    {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT `item_id` FROM `#__kart_items` where parent='com_zoo' AND `product_id`=".$this->_item->id. "";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $forsale = $db->loadResult();
    if (!empty($forsale)) 
    {
    print "<div class='buyit'><a href=" .$this->app->route->item($this->_item). ">Buy It!</a></div>";
    }

    }
    }

  [1]: http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/create-a-custom-element
```